# Error - did not find required record type

Tags: ios, swift, record, cloudkit

So I feel as though I am close to cracking my first CloudKit practice but at the last moment Xcode is unable to find my record type: "DiningTypes".

I have no errors or warnings in Xcode. My CloudKit dashboard is set to development. I have the correct spelling of my record type. So I am unsure what the dilemma is. I may be stretching here but have a wrong function but most of the code is taken almost verbatim from a working tutorial.

Therefore, am I missing a function or using a missed function or some other dastardly nuisance?

```
var categories: Array<CKRecord> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func fetchdiningtypes()
    {
        let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        let publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "DiningTypes", predicate: predicate)

        publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            }
            else
            {
                for result in results!
                {
                    self.categories.append(result)
                }

                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock( { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }

   fetchdiningtypes()
}
```

Comment: Are you looking at the right container in the CloudKit dashboard? Does the correct container actually have a record type of "DiningTypes"?

Comment: At the moment, Im using the default container and it does have the correct record type "DiningTypes"

Comment: That's not what I asked. Your code is fine. In your web browser where you are logged into the CloudKit dashboard, have you selected the correct container associated with this app?

Comment: ohhhh, I see what you mean.  Let me get back to you in a second.

Comment: I had forgotten that I was personally responsible for changing the container of each app.  Thank you, sir!